# Multiplication between two cells of a JTable in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I enter values in the cells of the 1st row of columns "Units" and "Price" , column "Amount"; the columns cell value should be set to the product of unit and amount . Which listener should I use? Please help as I'm new to Java.

**CODE:**

```
 JTable jTable1;
 DefaultTableModel mod=new DefaultTableModel();
        mod.addColumn("No");
        mod.addColumn("Item ID");
        mod.addColumn("Units");
        mod.addColumn("Amount");
        mod.addColumn("UOM");
        mod.addColumn("Delivery Date");
        mod.addColumn("Total Amount");
        mod.addColumn("Notes");
        mod.addColumn("Received");
        mod.addRow(new Object [][] {
            {1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
        });
        jTable1.setModel(mod);
        jTable1.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Comment: You might try creating a custom `DefaultTableModel` who's [`getValueAt(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) for that column returns the result of the multiplication of the other two cells.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is to implement a `TableModel` so that it automatically returns the  result of the product of unit and amount. Here is a small demonstration of what I mean (to add a new row, simply double click below the table):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTable3 {

    protected void initUI() {
        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return Integer.class;
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    return Double.class;
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                if (column == 2) {
                    Integer i = (Integer) getValueAt(row, 0);
                    Double d = (Double) getValueAt(row, 1);
                    if (i != null && d != null) {
                        return i * d;
                    } else {
                        return 0.0;
                    }
                }
                return super.getValueAt(row, column);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return column == 0 || column == 1;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
                super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 2);
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return "Quantity";
                case 1:
                    return "Price";
                case 2:
                    return "Total";
                }
                return super.getColumnName(column);
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 3;
            }
        };
        final JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    if (table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint()) < 0) {
                        model.addRow(new Vector());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        model.addRow(new Vector());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestTable3.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.add(scrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTable3().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the result:
[image: Result]

Comment: +1 please to add `return Double.class;` to the `2nd case` too, or  to use default: statement with `return Double.class;`

Comment: @mKorbel they both do return `Double.class` (case 1 and case 2: `case 1:
                case 2:
                    return Double.class;`). Case 1 "falls" into case 2

Answer (score 2):

> When I enter values in the cells of the 1st row of columns "Units" and
>   "Price" , column "Amount"; the columns cell value should be set to the
>   product of unit and amount

- have look at [TableModelListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange)
- have to read the [Oracle JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)