# How to add functions on columns of table in Java?

Tags: java, swing, awt, spreadsheet

I am new in programming and I am looking for a way to add functions on columns of table in java just like MS Excel.

Comment: What do you mean by "functions?"

Comment: Its like if i want to add the values of one column and the other column the answer should appear in third column.

Comment: So you mean if the user types in something like "sum(x,y)" you can perform the calculation...?

Comment: @Jason i haven't tried anything because i am new programming i don't know how to even start. :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes exactly

Comment: How well do you know the `JTable` API?

Comment: Yes i hav made the jtable on netbeans

Comment: Does that mean you want a parser in the cell (ie: to parse different commands like sum(x,y), sub(x,y), etc.) or you just want to know say, how to make a third column rely on the values used in the first two columns and perform the relevant operations in the backend, displaying the results in the last column?

Comment: @CanadianDavid Yes i want parser kind of functionality if its possible,otherwise the other option would also work.

Comment: It would take a great deal of work (even by someone who is experienced) to turn a `JTable` into anything like what a spreadsheet could achieve.  Save this project for a long while later and start with simpler tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement your own `DefaultTableModel` or `AbstractTableModel` to be able to output your own values in the third column. Another user has posted an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284027/2557554) which demonstrates how to multiply the first two columns together and output the result in the third column. In the example, you can double click the JTable to add another row and you will notice that the results are always multiplied and shown in the third column. These calculations are performed in the custom table model.

In regards to a parser in the cells, I imagine you would have to override the `getValueAt(int row, int column)` function and check if the value at the given row and column follows the function syntax (ie: in MS Excel, functions always start with an equal sign). If the value does follow the syntax, you can strip the relevant details and then perform the necessary calculations.